# ClassNotFoundException when using Class.forName("org.mysql.Driver"); in android

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html) I am attempting to connect to my newly created DB instance in an Android activity. I downloaded the MySQL Connector linked in the guide, put the jar file in the libs folder of my project, and made sure my gradle included `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in the dependencies.

From here I have tried a multitude of path names in the argument for Class.forName(). These include, but are not limited to, "org.mysql.Driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", and "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver". All of these attempts result in the same ClassNotFoundException.

Did I miss a step in adding the library or are none of the path names correct?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Drive in android? bad idea

Comment: I understand that it is not the best idea, but I am using this program for testing purposes and not planning to provide it to anyone else. As such, the weak security provided by the driver will not be an issue.

Comment: It is not just a bad idea for security reasons. Android has diverged from normal Java, so Java libraries do not necessarily work under Android. As far as I know, the MySQL Connector/J 8 library doesn't work under Android at all. In any case, you should post the full exception stack trace.